# Long task in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/zferN/) I see the whole page at once ? Thanks !

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<15; i++) {
        sleep(100);
        $("div").append("<span>--- " + i + " ---<br /></span>");
    }

    function sleep(milliseconds) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
            if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you only tested that on JSFiddle? I suspect that JSFiddle is preventing the result from being drawn until the script is done running, because when I change the `sleep(100)` to `sleep(1000)`, it takes a whole lot longer to load.

Comment: Oh, and you should probably be using a `while (true)` as opposed to a `for` loop.

Comment: @Austin: It's not JSFiddle, that's just the way Javascript currently works on browsers. That sleep function doesn't do what he wants it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Javascript on web browsers is single-threaded (although that's changing; see below) and virtually no browser updates its UI while the (main) Javascript thread is busy. All your `sleep` function does is block everything for 100ms, it doesn't let the browser do anything else like update its UI (e.g., doesn't "yield").

There are a couple of ways to do what you're trying to do:

1. Use the new [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) stuff; but note that it's [not widely-supported yet](http://html5readiness.com/).
2. Make your loop a function that calls itself via `setTimeout`. That way, your code is yielding to the browser and letting it update its UI.

Here's a *simple* example of how you might apply #2 above to your code:

```
$(function() {
    var i;

    doOne();

    function doOne() {
        $("div").append("<span>--- " + i + " ---<br /></span>");
        if (i++ < 15) {
            setTimeout(doOne, 0);   // <== Won't really be zero, browsers clamp it at ~10
        }
    }

});
```

If you have a lot of loop iterations (e.g., a couple of hundred instead of 15), it may well be worth doing a chunk of them on each iteration rather than yielding on each iteration; the yield takes a measureable time (typically ~10-15ms).

Comment: Unless you use Web Workers if they are implemented in your browser: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/

Comment: @the_drow: Um...that was my way #1. :-)

Comment: This recursion becomes problematic when the number of iterations is high (say 10000). Firefox 3.6.3 says "too much recursion". Do you have any workaround for that ?

Comment: @Misha: There's no recursion at all in the example above. The call to `setTimeout` returns immediately, and then `doOne` returns immediately, unwinding the stack. Then after a brief interval, the browser calls `doOne` again, which does the next bit. Did you pehaps put `()` after `doOne` in the `setTimeout` call? They need *not* to be there, you're referencing the function, not calling it directly.

Comment: @Misha: Looks like web workers are supported on current versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera, which only leaves IE (the biggest, I know) out in the cold. May well be worth looking into using them, at least optionally, with a fallback like the above for IE. I bet IE9 will have web workers.

Comment: Now I understand that it is not a recursion :) I hope that I will be able to apply this technique in my program.
Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: @Misha: Good deal, glad that was helpful. :-)

Comment: It definitely was ! Good that there are people that are glad to help like you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to hand over some processing time to the UI since javascript is single threaded, like this:

```
$(function() {
    function appendDiv(i) {
        $("div").append("<span>--- " + i + " ---<br /></span>");
        if(i < 14) 
            setTimeout(function() { appendDiv(i+1); }, 100);  
    }
    appendDiv(0);
});​
```

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pyccP/)

You could also use an interval for what you want, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/pyccP/1/):

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $("div").append("<span>--- " + i++ + " ---<br /></span>");
        if(i == 15) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 100);
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for examples. setInterval is not what I need. I have a big calculation in Javascript that takes ~10sec, and I want to do some updates during this calculation to improve user's experience. As I mentioned above, the recursion with setTimeout becomes problematic when the number of iterations is high (say 10000). Do you have any other idea ?

Comment: @Misha - What are you doing that takes that long? :) Can it not be sent with the page, pre-computed on the server?  That would be much faster than JavaScript.

Comment: I definitely could do the long task on server side, but this would require a big change in my program. I want to check if this can be done in Javascript.

Comment: @Misha - I *strongly* suggest you do that, it's a much better user experience.